# Select and Rename multiple columns dplyr pipe within select call

Tags: r, dplyr

More out of curiosity, but I was curious if more complex tidyselect and renaming could be combined.

What I mean is with a simple select statement in a dplyr pipe you can also rename the selected columns.
e.g.
`df1 %>% select(Facility = facility_name)`

But for something using this example data

```
df1 <- tibble(Location = c("here", "there"), 
              facility_name = c("fac_1", "fac_2"),
              pct_lessequal_4wks_current = c(0.56, 0.79),
              pct_lessequal_4wks_baseline = c(0.45, 0.65),
              pct_lessequal_4wks_pre_mandate = c(0.36, 0.89))
```

is it possible to do a one line select and rename all the pct_lessequal columns to just have their suffix?

I do the selection with

```
 df1 %>% select(Location, starts_with("pct))
```

however I've been unable to figure out how to pair it with a rename statement within the line.

if I want to do it over two lines it works easily with this

```
df1 %>% select(Location, starts_with("pct")) %>%
  rename_all(~stringr::str_replace(., "pct_lessequal_4wks_", ""))
```

Not sure if this is possible or not. I haven't managed to find an example of it on SO or elsewhere so far, so any input would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the solution you have presented using `select` and `rename_all` (this function has been superseded by `rename_with`, which allows for the renaming of a tidy-selection of columns) would be the preferred way to go. There may be ways to accomplish this in a single `select` statement, but those solutions would be overly complicated compared to what you have already figured out and certainly conflict with the readability.

Comment: This is a good question! (though I agree with LMc that this is more code-golf than anything else). In older versions of `dplyr::select_()` you could have a named vector and use `.dots` - ie. if you had the named vector `newnames <- setNames(names(df1), gsub("pct_lessequal_4wks_", "", names(df1)))` then you could simply run `df1 %>% select_(.dots = newnames)` and you'll get exactly what you want. But `select_` has been depreciated (though still works) and I dont know what has replaced the `.dots` function in `select`, if anything